# How to read a json object in prototype

Tags: javascript, asp.net, prototypejs

I can't get my returned data's properties. I am very new on prototype. Where is my mistake?

Here is my codes :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script>
    var xRequest = new Ajax.Request('PrototypeTest.aspx/Test', {
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        onSuccess: function (val) {
            var brands= val.responseText.evalJSON();
            alert(brands);
        },
        onerror: function (val) {
            alert('hata');

        }
    });
</script>

   [WebMethod]
    public static string Test()
    {
        List<brand> brands = new List<brand>();
        brands.Add(new brand()
            {
                Name = "BMW",
                IsActive = true
            });

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return json.Serialize(brands);
    }
```

Comment: What's in responseText? Do you get what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line

```
`var brands= val.responseText.evalJSON();`
```

to

```
`var brands= JSON.parse((JSON.parse(val.responseText));`
```

or

```
`var brands= val.responseText.evalJSON().d.evalJSON();`
```

Answer (score 0):

If your backend script sends the header `Content-type: application/json` the `Ajax.Request()` method will auto convert your response to JSON and it will exist in `val.responseJSON` in your example.

setting `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` in the `Ajax.Request()` is not needed in this instance.

To make ASP.NET add a custom header I think you use

`Response.AppendHeader("Content-type", "application/json");`

but I am not a ASP.NET developer